# find nth term of series according to given conditions

Tags: python

question: in a sequence, if d1 = difference b/w an element and the next element and d2 = difference between even element and next element, write a code to find the nth term of sequence. 
input: a,b,c - the first 3 numbers of the sequence and n is the the position of the number you want to find.
example: if a = 97, b = 100, c = 98 and n = 5 then print 99

my code got accepted but i was wondering if there was another (easier) way to solve this?

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
n=int(input())
d1=b-a
d2=c-b
if n%2==0:
    n=(a+(n/2)*d1 + ((n/2)-1)*d2) 
    print(int(n))
else:
    n=a+((n-1)/2)*d1 +((n-1)/2)*d2
    print(int(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of floor division:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
n=int(input())
d1=b-a
d2=c-b
print(a + n//2*d1 + (n-1)//2*d2)
```